# Nginx setup for static files

Tags: nginx, nginx-location, nginx-config

I am working to implement static content in the Nginx server. We use a single Nginx server to host multiple applications and the static content location is different for each application.

**Scenario:**
Implement static content for images (Examples: gif|jpg|jpeg|png|svg) for each application.

**Example Application Urls:** 
https://www.example.com/application1/images/welcome.png
https://www.example.com/application2/images/banner.png

**My code:**

```
           location /application1 {
               location ~.*\.(gif|jpg|jpeg|png|svg)$ {
                       alias /var/lib/www/application1_static/images;
                        try_files $uri 404;
               }
           }
           location /application2 {
               location ~.*\.(gif|jpg|jpeg|png|svg)$ {
                       alias /var/lib/www/application2_static/images;
                        try_files $uri 404;
               }
           }
```

The nested location block does not work well together. Individually, when I test, it works.
I tried using with root clause, but it did not help.

Experts, please review and help me to complete the implementation.

Thank you.

Comment: There are a number of things wrong with your existing configuration. I think the solution you need is: `location /application1/images { alias /var/lib/www/application1_static/images; }`

Comment: Thanks for the comments. There are several folders that need to be converted to static for each application. "Images" is one such folder. Hence it is not possible to redirect each folder and hence need to filter through file extension.
File patterns: gif|png|jpeg|jpg|css|js|ico|svg|xml|json|html|md|ttf|woff2|pdf|docx|doc

Comment: To use `alias` within a regular expression `location` you need to provide the full path to the file. For example: `location ~ ^/application1/(.*\.(gif|jpg|jpeg|png|svg))$ { alias /var/lib/www/application1_static/$1; }`

Comment: Thank you, Richard. It worked.